# Что такое структурированные файлы с индексным доступом и как с ними работать

Tags: c, база-данных, файлы

Приветсвую!

Возник вопрос с тем что такое структурированные файлы с индексным доступом. Дело в том что мне нужно создать два файла(один с расширением .fl, а другой с расширением .ind).
И вот вопрос в том как для начала их создать, а второй как их открыть и наполнить информацией(или же это можно сделать без открытия файлов такого формата). В условии задачи пишется о том что индексированный файл состоит из двух частей(собственно говоря из файла формата .fl и файла формата .ind). При этом упоминается и о том что файл формата .ind это индексная таблица которая содержит какую то информацию о предметной области.

Цель работы: Научится работать из структурированными файлами на основе лишь только языка Си

Окончательная формулировка вопроса: Как создать файлы подобного типа(софт или командная строка или еще что-то) и как наполнить эти файлы какими нибудь тестовыми данными

Comment: Такие вопросы лучше задавать автору методички.

Comment: ну и на лекциях что-то давалось наверное

Comment: @PavelGridin Как раз ничего об этом не упоминалось к сожалению

Comment: ну тогда ищите по словам хэш-индексация в субд

Comment: @PavelGridin Но в задании мне запрещено пользоваться СУБД

Comment: Структурированный файл, простыми словами (если бинарный), содержит записи одинаковой длинны. Например там записаны структуры фирсированной длинны. Поэтому по ним легко искать данные. А индекс нужен для, например, сохранения номеров этих структур после сортировки по какому-либо элементу структуры или хэш функций для чего-нибудь. Можно и csv файл считать таковым, но текстовым

Comment: ну и не пользуйтесь, просто поймите принцип работы

Comment: В файле .fl вам надо хранить собственно записи (данные) файла. Каждая запись имеет несколько полей (обычно фиксированной длины). А в файле .ind вам надо хранить значения полей (тех, которые подлежат индексации) вместе со списком адресов таких записей в файле .fl, которые содержат поля с таким значением. Обычно сначала создается файл .fl, а затем по его содержимому строятся индексы. Далее, при изменении .fl вы должны согласовано менять .ind (для этого вы должны разработать API для доступа к данным в .fl, который используется во всех программах, опрерирующих данными в .fl)

Answer (score 2):

> что такое структурированные файлы с индексным доступом.

Ваш препод, наверное, мой ровесник, а может даже - старше :-)

То, о чём Вы говорите, это изобретение фирмы IBM. Они появились в IBM OS/360 в шестидесятых годах прошлого века.

Идея заключается в чём:

1. В отсортированном файле можно легко и быстро найти нужную запись хотя бы методом деления пополам.
2. В отсортированном файле очень трудно выполнять операции вставки/удаления записей. Каждый раз приходится сдвигать (в среднем) половину файла.
3. Вот и была предложена идея ISAM - индексно-последовательный метод доступа.

Берём диск. На каждой дорожке резервируем (к примеру) 50% пустого места. Заливаем данные (отсортированные!) в рабочие области на всех дорожках подряд. Отдельно создаём индексный файл (отсортированный!) в котором для каждой дорожки прописано значение минимального индекса записей на этой дорожке.

Таким образом, когда нужно найти какую-то запись по ключу, то поиск идёт в два этапа:

1. В индексном файле ищем дорожку
2. На дорожке ищем запись

Вставляем новые записи в область расширения соответствующей дорожки.

Дураку понятно, что при интенсивной работе, область расширения рано или поздно закончится. Предусматривалось два варианта:

1. Попытаться уместить новые записи в основной области, заново отсортировав все записи на дорожке. С учётом удалённых записей это могло сработать.
2. Не помещающиеся записи перенести в т.н. "Индекс второго уровня".

Я не буду более подробно распространятся, так как с появлением СУБД эта технология приказала долго жить... И было это очень давно.